# echo %JAVA_HOME% returns %JAVA_HOME% on Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

I have installed Java and set up an environment variable on Windows 10 Pro.

When I try to verify its presence with `echo %JAVA_HOME%`, I am not getting the expected output in PowerShell:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

output (verbatim):

```
%JAVA_HOME%
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading the official documentation. I found that to retrieve/print environmental variable using Windows PowerShell. We need to execute the below command

> $Env:JAVA_HOME

Comment: Indeed. The relevant help topic is [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables).